# Why is ActionSupport in Struts a class and not an interface?

Tags: java, struts2, struts

Interfaces give more flexibility to Java developers than concrete classes do. I am new to the Struts framework, and I'm confused about the Struts developers' decision to make `ActionSupport` a class. In my opinion, it should be an interface. Why did they do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the documentation [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.9/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html)

> Provides a default implementation for the most common actions. See the documentation for all the interfaces this class implements for more detailed information.

It is actually a default implementation for the **interface** `Action`. And since it is an implementation it cannot be an interface because interfaces are 100% abstract.

Answer (score 0):

From the struts documentation:

> Class ActionSupport Provides a default implementation for the most common actions. See the documentation for all the interfaces this class implements for more detailed information.

http://struts.apache.org/2.1.2/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely an architecture decision. `ActionSupport` gives the user very useful resources inside their own actions so, without necessity to expose it elsewhere inside the API. The user intended to extend `ActionSupport` for their own actions to utilize its resources.
The `Action` interface obey the user to implement the `execute` method, as we know is not necessary.

Actions are simple POJOs they don't need to extend or implement something.